# Custom vector that uses less memory than std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, vectors

I'm using vectors to create matrix and the vector itself is consuming a large space. So I implemented a version that would use less memory and, if possible, be as fast or faster than `std::vector`.

How can I improve the performance and is there anything that should be changed?

```
#ifndef __DATAARRAY_H__
#define __DATAARRAY_H__
#include <memory>
#include "core/Exceptions/ArgumentException.h"

template <size_t S> class Sizer { };
    namespace Core
    {
#pragma pack(1)
        template <class DataType, class MaxSizeType>
        class DataArray
        {
        public:
            DataArray() :m_iDataSize(0), m_aData(nullptr), m_iDataCapacity(0){
            }
            DataArray(MaxSizeType size) :m_iDataSize(0){
                _Reserve(size);
            }

            DataArray(const DataArray& dArray)
            {
                _Reserve(dArray.m_iDataCapacity);
                _CopyData(dArray);
            }
            void reserve(MaxSizeType size){
            }

            void resize(MaxSizeType size){
                if (size < m_iDataSize)
                {
                    _Delete_Data(m_aData + size, m_aData + m_iDataSize);
                    m_iDataSize = size;
                }
                else if (m_iDataSize < size){
                    _Reserve(size);
                    DataType* pData = (m_aData + m_iDataSize);
                    for (; pData < m_aData + size; ++pData) {
                        new (pData)DataType;
                    }
                    m_iDataSize = size;
                }
            }

            void push_back(DataType element){
                if (m_iDataCapacity <= m_iDataSize)
                {
                    _Reserve(m_iDataCapacity + 1);
                }
                new (m_aData + m_iDataSize)DataType(element);
                m_iDataSize++;
            }

            DataType& operator[](MaxSizeType id)
            {
                if (id < 0 || id >= size()) 
                   throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
                return m_aData[id];
            }

            DataType& operator=(const DataArray& dArray)
            {
                if (this == &dArray)
                    return *this;
                _Delete_m_aData();
                _Reserve(dArray.m_iDataCapacity);
                _CopyData(dArray);
                return *this;
            }

            MaxSizeType size(){
                return m_iDataSize;
            }

            MaxSizeType Capacity(){
                return m_iDataCapacity;
            }

            ~DataArray(){
                _Delete_m_aData();
            }
        protected:
            inline void _Reserve(MaxSizeType size){
                if (size > m_iDataCapacity){
                    DataType* new_Data = (DataType*)std::realloc(m_aData, sizeof(DataType)*size);
                    if (new_Data != NULL){
                        m_aData = new_Data;
                        m_iDataCapacity = size;
                    }
                    else{
                        _Delete_m_aData();
                        throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
                    }
                }
            }
            inline void _CopyData(const DataArray& dArray){
                DataType* pOrig = dArray.m_aData;
                DataType* pDest = m_aData;
                DataType* pOriEnd = pOrig + dArray.m_iDataSize;
                for (; pOrig < pOriEnd; ++pDest, ++pOrig)
                {
                    new (pDest)DataType(*pOrig);
                }
                m_iDataSize = dArray.m_iDataSize;
            }

            inline void _Delete_m_aData()
            {
                _Delete_Data(m_aData, m_aData + m_iDataSize);
                m_iDataSize = 0;
                m_iDataCapacity = 0;
                free(m_aData);
            }

            inline void _Delete_Data(DataType* begin, DataType* end)
            {
                DataType* pData = begin;
                for (; pData < end; ++pData) {
                    ((DataType*)pData)->~DataType();
                }
            }
            MaxSizeType m_iDataCapacity;
            MaxSizeType m_iDataSize;
            DataType* m_aData;
        };
#pragma pack()
}
#endif
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: What's the class-template `Sizer` for?

Comment: `if possible, be as fast or faster than std::vector` Yep; not going to happen. `std::vector` is highly optimized, has had thousands of people look at the code for over a decade picking it apart and making it as efficient as possible. You are not going to come in and write something faster or more stable. If you do things perfectly you may achieve as fast but that's unlikely.

Comment: Are these actually vectors that change size at runtime?  In one comment you mentioned you're creating 23 million of them for processing 3d data, which to me suggests a bulk body of data that you have more information about than you are actually using.  Is it possible that you might know the size of each vector beforehand?  If so, much of the complexity of a vector like class goes away.

Comment: Like @Cort said, you will save *much* more memory and get better performance using a single `std::vector` to store a 2D or 3D array.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new/28841507#28841507 for example.  You only need each row to be a separate `vector` if you need to add a column on the fly without shuffling around all existing row data (or if you need a "ragged" array where different rows are different lengths).  You want your whole matrix stored in one big block of memory, not each row allocated and tracked separately.

Comment: As @LokiAstari said, you are not better than the thousands of people who have looked at the std container implementations. You are not going to do it better. Further you *are* going to introduce bugs. The only people who care about stuff like this are embedded programmers and even they don't care about a few extra bytes on a vector. I have asked the people that wrote the software running on some of the most important space missions of the 90's and 00's. (which to be fair are all written in c not c++)

Comment: Also note. You did add a couple of bugs. Also because you don't support move semantics (both for the container and for objects being placed in the container) you are going to miss out on some optimizations that std::vector does get. Also resizing is why more inefficient in your class.

Comment: If you are implementing a 2D array (that has a fixed size determined at runtime). Then a better choice would be a wrapper around a single std::vector. Then map access to the 2D array into acccess to elements in the vector. Note Data locality will them become your major issue. Which means you need to decide if your 2D array is row or column orientated.

Comment: Read this: Basically using a std::vector is as close to using a builtin language array as you can get. [Is std::vector so much slower than plain arrays? The Answer is no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays/3664349#3664349)

Comment: Read this: [How to implement 2D array access over 1D array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3755221/14065)

Comment: I agree with all the things you are saying but the problem im solving is very specific. I´m using these arrays to cache data extrated from 3D models. The reason im not using arrays is because i dont know the size up front. On my current problem i saved 600mb o memory just because of these 12bytes of difference. Regarding the performance it was also improved. I´m storing on this vector shared_ptr so part of the problems mentioned regarding moving the elements does not happen. I think i should have specified better my goals.

Comment: Are you creating a boatload of teeny `DataArrays`? This is the one case where you have a chance to beat the performance of `std::vector`, but it'll require you to store an array of size N and a pointer to it. The pointer turns into a dynamic array if the size exceeds `N`. This can actually beat `vector` in this very narrow kind of usage solely for the locality of reference you get, but it's less generally-applicable than `vector`. For example, you might be able to assume that most of your polygons are quads -- in which case you can use `4` for N. The free store will only get used...

Comment: ... in that case if `N > 5`. It'll also tend to be teenier than vector provided that most of the containers have `N == 4`.

Comment: However, if you have a boatload of teeny containers like this, the best way to get a compact and fast result is kind of lose that structure -- turn it into one flat kind of list (not a bunch of little lists). For meshes it's tempting to create a bunch of little growable containers, but if memory and efficiency concerns are tight, you want to coalesce those little containers into bigger blocks of memory and avoid that kind of overhead of extra pointers and capacity variables and so forth. You want to take a C-like memory allocator mindset if your needs are tight enough: back to bits and bytes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Size Requirements**

You talk about wanting to "use less memory" than `std::vector`. But `std::vector` doesn't use that much memory. It's three pointers. I guess if you set your `MaxSizeType` to `int` instead of `size_t`, you can have a vector of 16 bytes instead of 24, but I would really have to see what you're doing that that difference should matter.

**Performance**

There's two glaring issues that jump out at me as far as performance goes. I suspect this would be substantially slower than `std::vector`.

First one is on `push_back`:

```
void push_back(DataType element){
    if (m_iDataCapacity <= m_iDataSize)
    {
        _Reserve(m_iDataCapacity + 1);
    }
    new (m_aData + m_iDataSize)DataType(element);
    m_iDataSize++;
}
```

First, you're taking your `DataType` by value. That's incurring an extra copy, which you don't want to do. Secondly, your resize policy is increasing capacity *by one*. This means that your `push_back()` is expected \$O(n)\$. There's an easy explanation for this too: once we reach our capacity, we will have to `_Reserve()` on *every* subsequent `push_back()`, which means we're copying \$n\$ elements every time. The right thing to do is to increase capacity by a constant factor.

The next issue comes from indexing:

```
DataType& operator[](MaxSizeType id)
{
    if (id < 0 || id >= size()) 
       throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
    return m_aData[id];
}
```

First, the exception is misleading. A better exception type would be [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range), and a message indicating this - since the issue isn't that we ran out of memory. That's an error that we would throw if allocation fails (in `_Reserve`, you do the same thing - there you should throw [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)).

But the main problem is this kills performance because on every lookup, we have a branch. Every time. And branches are slow. That's why on `std::vector`, `operator[]` is defined simply as:

```
reference
operator[](size_type __n) 
{    
    return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n);
}
```

If you want bounds checking, you can provide a separate member function called [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

**Other Issues**

You're missing a lot of other nice features that `std::vector` provides:

- Missing iterators, `begin()`, and `end()`.
- Missing `const` overloads of member functions
- This cast is unnecessary, since `pData` is already a `DataType`.

  ```
  ((DataType*)pData)->~DataType();
  ```

Comment: First of all thanks Barry for your help.
Regarding the size im going to use unsigned char which will save me 14bytes since im allocating 23000000 vectors thats alot of memory.
Regarding the memory allocation. i´m not using new to alocate memory  . Im actually using std::realloc the line new (pDest)DataType(*pOrig); does not allocates memory, thats why i use free.

Comment: @JaimeMachado 2.3 *million* vectors?!?

Comment: 23milion, I´m using this code to process large 3D files.

Comment: Last time I had to implement a similar thing (think `std::valarray` for operators but `std::array` for the rest) the *branch itself* in the `operator[]` was mostly irrelevant since it's predicted extremely well by the branch predictor (the check always fails) and the compiler put the exception-throwing code out of the hot path. The real problem was that the exception-creation code was big enough to prevent the function from being inlined, so it was the function call overhead to kill performance. Separating the throw in a function may give the bounds checking at extremely reduced cost.

Comment: Do you really need dynamically resizable vectors, or would a far simpler and more efficient `std::array` suffice?

Comment: A branch is the "main thing" that kills performance!?  A successfully-predicted branch is practically free, while even a failed branch prediction _(which will be rare in this case)_ is still faster than a single integer division.  And all of these things are **orders of magnitude** faster than a single allocation.  The real performance-killer here was the excess allocations in `push_back()`.  I wrote a blog post relating to timings [here](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/368/how-fast-are-computers-in-everyday-terms).

Comment: @BlueRaja I said the main problem about the operator, not the main problem of the whole class.

Answer (score 8):

- There's an issue with your naming convention. Names starting with an underscore, followed by a capital letter (e.g.: `_Reserve`) and double underscore (e.g.: `__DATAARRAY_H__`), are using a notation reserved for future expansion of the Standard Library and compiler extensions. To avoid name clashes, prefer not using the underscore prefix on your own names. You can find more details about the naming rules of C++ in here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654)
- None of your class methods are `const`, which means I can't, for instance, call `operator[]` on a `const DataArray` instance. Methods that don't change member data should always be declared as const. More about const member functions in [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns).
- Consider adding a [move constructor and operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). It might optimize your class quite a bit by allowing the compiler to avoid unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 4):

`realloc` essentially does a `memcpy` to the newly allocated buffer. This will create *issues* if the move construction is non-trivial and/or the moved-from object still needs proper destruction.

If this is the case for the `DataType` then you should allocate a new buffer and placement-move-construct into the new buffer, destruct the objects in the old buffer and finally free the old buffer.

Comment: A link on SO for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706528/is-it-safe-to-realloc-memory-allocated-with-new oops, nearly forgot to vote ;-)

Comment: +1 this is the real issue here.
The class _has_ to have something like this: `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<DataType>::value, "Only trivial types!")`

Comment: @Shaggi or use a mutually template-disabled pair of reserve functions where one uses realloc for trivial types and the other that does the method I described for all others.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, you're right, that would be a perfect solution.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Would this problem happen even if im not allocating memory with new. If you take a look at line new (m_aData + m_iDataSize)DataType(element); I´m not alocating memory i´m using the memory that was previously allocated with realloc. And before freeing the memory i call the destructor for each object.

Comment: @JaimeMachado it can be, for example if the objects have are also in an intrusive doubly-linked list so the move needs to update the pointers of the neighboring values.

Answer (score 2):

#### Reserved Identifiers:

An identifier with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for use by the system in all scopes.

Thus the following are bad:

```
            inline void _Reserve(MaxSizeType size)
            inline void _CopyData(const DataArray& dArray)
            inline void _Delete_m_aData()    
            inline void _Delete_Data(DataType* begin, DataType* end)
```

#### Use constructors to initialize all members

```
            DataArray(MaxSizeType size) :m_iDataSize(0){
                _Reserve(size);
            }
```

Looks good. But `_Reserve()` does not always initialize all the remaining members!! (If size == 0) the two remaining members are left undefined.

Also doing this is bad practice  because you are assuming that somebody that modifies `_Reserve()` knows the contract it has with the constructor (ie that it must initialize those two members). The contract is not specified anywhere...

#### Dead code should be removed

```
            void reserve(MaxSizeType size){
            }
```

#### Pass values by reference.

```
            void push_back(DataType element){
                         ///     ^^^   parameter copied
```

#### Resizing for more than you need.

```
                if (m_iDataCapacity <= m_iDataSize)
                {
                    _Reserve(m_iDataCapacity + 1);
                }
```

This is very inefficient if you add lots of elements in a row. Once you reach the initial size every time you push back you are reserving more capacity. When you hit the limit reserve more than you need so that you don't have to reserve every time.

#### Provide const versions of some methods:

```
            DataType& operator[](MaxSizeType id)
```

There should be two version of this method. This will allow your object to use in const contexts (thus allowing you to build const correct code).

```
            DataType&       operator[](MaxSizeType id);
            DataType const& operator[](MaxSizeType id) const;
```

#### Operator [] is non checking

```
                if (id < 0 || id >= size()) 
                   throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
```

For efficiency `operator[]` does not check bounds (as after testing you have fixed all those bugs). For code where the index is calculated at run time and needs to be validated you usually provide the method `at(MaxSizeType id)`.

#### That's not the correct exception:

```
                if (id < 0 || id >= size()) 
                   throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
```

This is an out of range access. There is already an exception specifically for this. Alos it has nothing to do with "enought" memory.

#### Prefer to use the copy and swap idiom

This assignment constructor is not exception safe.

If `_Reserve` throws an exception then the objects data is not in a consistent state. Because you have called the destructor on all the members (but not reset the size of the array and not copied new values into their place).

You should never destroy old data if there is a possibility of failure.

```
            DataType& operator=(const DataArray& dArray)
            {
                if (this == &dArray)
                    return *this;
                _Delete_m_aData();
                _Reserve(dArray.m_iDataCapacity);  // If this throws your out of luck.
                _CopyData(dArray);                 // Because this is not called
                return *this;                      // to set the correct members.
            }
```

#### These look like it should be const methods.

```
            MaxSizeType size(){
                return m_iDataSize;
            }

            MaxSizeType Capacity(){
                return m_iDataCapacity;
            }
```

#### There is a bug in _Reserve.

If this is called from the assignment operator after all the elements have been deleted. Now if there is a realoc failure. The you are calling `_Delete_m_aData()` which calls `_Delete_Data()` which calls the destructor on the objects again. Even though they have previously been destroyed.

```
                    else{
                        _Delete_m_aData();
                        throw std::invalid_argument("Not enought memory");
                    }
```

#### Different types of brace style

Be consistent.

```
        DataArray(const DataArray& dArray)
        {
            _Reserve(dArray.m_iDataCapacity);
            _CopyData(dArray);
        }
        void reserve(MaxSizeType size){
        }
```

#### Move Semantics not supported.

Your class does not provide move semantics. Supporting them would make your class a whole bunch more efficient it a lot of situations.

Comment: `void push_back(DataType element){` If the parameter must be copied in that function, sometimes it is preferred to pass it by value and move the copy in the function, so we don't need to overload on `DataType&&` and `const DataType&`.